# Where is AfxBeginThread function decleration?

Tags: c++, multithreading

this code using thread with AfxBeginThread function but i don't know what header file i should include to my project?

can anyone help

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;   

    cout << "Press ESCAPE to terminate program\r\n";
    AfxBeginThread(ServerThread,0);
    while(_getch()!=27);

    return nRetCode;
}
```

and what is the best way to use threads for a server that use winsock ....

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your code

Comment: i only want to know where is AfxBeginThread function is delared....

Comment: i recommend you go through   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should also add : `#define _AFXDLL`

here is an example :

```
#define _AFXDLL //<<===notice this

#include <Afxwin.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>



#include <iostream>
//other C++ standard headers here as required
using namespace std;



// The one and only application object
CWinApp theApp;



UINT ThreadProc(LPVOID pParam)
{
  return 0;
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    // initialize MFC
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        return 1;
    }

    int nRetCode = 0;  
    cout << "Press ESCAPE to terminate program\r\n";


    AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc,0);

    while(_getch()!=27);

    return nRetCode;

}
```

Comment: Error 1 error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d] c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h 24

Comment: 2 IntelliSense: #error directive: Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d] c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 24

Answer (score 1):

For `AfxBeginThread` you will need `afxwin.h`.

Comment: Error 1 error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d] c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h 24